# What is the right way to use service methods in Django?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

As an example, let's say I am building an Rest API using Django Rest Framework. Now as part of the application, a few methods are common across all views. My approach is that in the root directory, I have created a services.py file. Inside that module, is a class (CommonUtils) containing all the common utility methods. In that same services.py module I have instantiated an object of CommonUtils.

Now across the application, in the different views.py files I am importing the object from the module and calling the methods on that object. So, essentially I am using a singleton object for the common utility methods.

I feel like this is not a good design approach. So, I want to get an explanation for why this approach is not a good idea and What would the best practice or best approach to achieve the same thing, i.e use a set of common utility methods across all views.py files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question. Every project I've worked on ends up having a `utils` module/package because there is logic that is common to everything. However, those functions are typically small and have no business logic within them.

Comment: What benefits do you get from using the class?

Comment: The class is supposed to contain common functions used through out the django application. For eg. maybe pulling a sample data from somewhere, or maybe some logic for parsing  data etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is this the right design? Why? How to do better?

> I feel like this is not a good design approach. So, I want to get an explanation for why this approach is not a good idea and What would the best practice or best approach to achieve the same thing, i.e use a set of common utility methods across all views.py files.

Like @Dmitry Belaventsev wrote above, there is no general rule to solve this problem. This is a typical case of [cross-cutting-concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern).

> Now across the application, in the different views.py files I am importing the object from the module and calling the methods on that object. So, essentially I am using a singleton object for the common utility methods.

Yes, your implementation is actually a singleton and there is nothing wrong with it. You should ask yourself *what do you want to achieve* or *what do you really need*. There are a lot of solutions and you can start with the most basic one:

**A simple function in a python module**

```
# file is named utils.py and lives in the root directory

def helper_function_one(param):
   return transcendent_all_evil_of(param)

def helper_function_two(prename, lastname):
   return 'Hello {} {}'.format(prename, lastname)
```

In Python it is not uncommon to use just plain functions in a module. You can upgrade it to a method (and a class) if this is really necessary and you need the advantages of classes and objects.

You also can use a **class with static methods**:

```
# utils.py

class Utils():
   @staticmethod
   def helper_one():
       print('do something')
```

But you can see, this is nothing different than the solution with plain functions besides the extra layer of the class. But it has no further value.

You could also write a **Singleton Class** but in my opinion, this is not very pythonic, because you get the same result with a simple object instance in a module.